# "I'll not" vs "I won't" - when is which preferred?

Tags: contractions, negation

I know these two common contractions:

> I'll enjoy it
>
> I won't enjoy it

I wonder: can one use the first one with a negative?

> I'll not enjoy it.

Is this correct?

If so, when/how would one use it? Would it differ from "I won't" semantically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I'll not enjoy it" isn't incorrect, but it sounds a bit stilted or old-fashioned.

"I won't enjoy it" is the form more usually heard.

Either one should be understood to have the same meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Technically, the two are the same. *I'll not* and *I won't* both expand to *I will not*. In modern day, the first contraction is less seen, but that does not mean that it is not correct grammatically.